# C# Load JPG file, extract BitmapImage

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, jpeg, bitmapimage

I am trying to extract a BitmapImage from a JPG. This is the code I have:

```
FileStream fIn = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open); // source JPG
Bitmap dImg = new Bitmap(fIn);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
dImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
image.EndInit();
ms.Close();
```

image comes back with a 0 × 0 image, which of course means it didn't work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
public void Load(string fileName) 
{

    using(Stream BitmapStream = System.IO.File.Open(fileName,System.IO.FileMode.Open ))
    {
         Image img = Image.FromStream(BitmapStream);

         mBitmap=new Bitmap(img);
         //...do whatever
    }
}
```

Or you can just do this ([source](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-from-file.php)):

```cs
Bitmap myBmp = Bitmap.FromFile("path here");
```

Comment: I found my mistake: I need to use Image, not BitmapImage. I knew it didn't need to be complicated! This is the working code: Image image = Image.FromFile(sourceFileName, true);

Comment: Boy is this complicated initially! Image, BitmapImage, ImageSource, JpegImageDecoder etc. etc.

Comment: This is our job security, hehehe :)